# H.264 encoding in PowerDirector 10

Tags: video-editor, codec, encoding

I want to make videos for youtube, and I want to encode my videos in MPEG-4, but the PowerDirector 10 says that I need to activate the video codification by hardware and I activated it in the preferences, but I can't activate it in the produce tab. I searched how to solve this and I didn't find anything useful. I downloaded K-lite mega codec pack and I downloaded the VLC H264 encoder, but i can't install the VLC H264 because I dont know how and I didn't find any tutorials about this.
So if someone could help me, I would appreciate.

**NOTE:** I don't know much about these codecs and stuff, but im not a noob at PC.

Answer (score 1):

I think [MeGUI](https://sourceforge.net/projects/megui/) is supposed to be a good front-end for x264 encoding.  ([x264](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html) is the same h.264 encoder that VLC uses.)

I don't know anything about powerdirector, so all I can say is that x264 is the best h.264 encoder (best quality vs. bitrate vs. cpu time tradeoff), and it's free.  It's what you should use to make files for upload to youtube.  (Use lots of bitrate, because youtube will decode and re-encode your video regardless of what you do.)